# Replace @variables@ within an application.properties from another project in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

We have an `application.properties` file in one project:

```
  src
   |--- main
        |--- resources
                 |--- application.properties
```

It contains some [Maven project property `@variables@`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html) to initialise some properties such as:

```
info.app.branch=@branch.name@
```

As I understand through some experimentation and the above documentation, these are replaced by `spring-boot-starter-parent`, before it copies them over into `target/classes/config`.

In a dependent project, we explicitly copy the `application.properties` file over from the parent project's JAR using the [Maven dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/).

```
<artifactItem>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
    <includes>config/application.properties</includes>
</artifactItem>
```

As such, it's already in the `target/classes/config` directory, and no replacement of the `@variables@` takes place.

How can I ensure that Spring boot correctly replaces these variables?

Comment: WHat is a reason behind the `@.....@` pattern?

Comment: @Nikolas They are Maven project properties. Please see this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know them :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way we solved this was to move the configuration files to a directory with a different name (we just called it 'config**s**'). The maven dependency plugin is then not unpacking directly into `config`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process-tools-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>the-parent</groupId>
                        <artifactId>the-artifact</artifactId>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>configs/application.properties</includes>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

We then use the Maven resources plugin to copy from `configs` into `config`, which is able to replace the `@properties@` for us:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
        <execution>
            <id>process-properties-placeholders</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <delimiters>
                    <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                </delimiters>
                <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes/configs</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/config</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Feels a bit awkward but you could probably specify the resource directory of the "dependent project" as the `outputDirectory`.
E.g:

```
<artifactItem>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
    <includes>config/application.properties</includes>
</artifactItem>
```

This way I would expect the Spring Boot Maven plugin to treat them as regular properties of the project and properly replace the variables.